# Script on end of VNC session on Mac

Tags: macos, vnc, screensharing

Is it possible to run a script at the end of a screen-sharing / VNC session to a Mac?

So far I have a bash script I'd like to run and the VNC works properly, I just have not found out a way to make the script run automatically at the end of a session.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no method of running a script on logout using VNC and OSX Screen Sharing.  I wish there better answer, but there is not.